# Repair Mercurial Warning "copy source of X not in parents of Y"

Tags: mercurial

I have a Mercurial "*copy source of X not in parents of*" warning that I'm trying to repair:

```
PS C:\repos\myProject-hg> hg verify
repository uses revlog format 1
checking changesets
checking manifests
crosschecking files in changesets and manifests
checking files
warning: copy source of 'XXX/YYY/__init__.py' not in parents of 3910fe874b90
702 files, 21 changesets, 753 total revisions
1 warnings encountered!
PS C:\repos\myProject-hg>
```

I have already localized the commit that caused the problem (using `hg clone -r X brokenRepo testRepo`) but am stumped on how to proceed with the repair as the [RepositoryCorruption](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RepositoryCorruption) link doesn't seem to address this specific type problem.

Answer (score 6):

According to [a post on the mercurial mailing lists](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.mercurial.general/23195) (scroll all the way down), this appears in repositories which have been committed to with very old versions of Mercurial.  Apparently, they incorrectly recorded certain operations.  [Mozilla regards this as harmless](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=644904).

If you're really desperate to get rid of these errors, you might try doing an `hg convert` on the repo, but that will change some/most/all of your changeset hashes, so it's probably not worth it.